# Get HTTP version of incoming request

Tags: node.js, http, express

How can I extract the HTTP version of an incoming request using express?

I need something like:

```
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    req.getHttpVersion() // 'HTTP 1.0'/'HTTP 1.1'/'HTTP 2.0'
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Request HTTP Version: ', req.httpVersion)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know tis is old , but still..
you can try :

```
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('AlpnProtocol: ' , req.connection.alpnProtocol,)
});
```