# How to know if a request is performed using HTTP 1.x or HTTP2

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, google-chrome-devtools, http2

I want to know if a request between a JavaScript Client and Node.js server is performed using HTTP1.x or HTTP2.

How I know in XMLHttpRequest, Chrome Console and Node.js what type of protocol is used ?

Comment: Are you asking how to do it programmatically or how to observe it? If later, then simply look in to Network tab of Dev tools browser and look for `HTTP/1.1` or `HTTP/2` in the request headers. You can also use `curl`.

Comment: Yes, how to observe it in browser dev tools and on client and server programmatically.

Comment: When the browser(client) and server both support HTTP/2 then it will be used for all calls from the browser. Can't you tell from your node js server?

Comment: I don't believe you can determine programmatically determine the HTTP/2 support on the browser by itself. NodeJS that information will be obtainable, however, but how to obtain it depends if you're using NodeJS's built in http server or if you're using a library like `express`.

Comment: Yes, I am using express. for example in node console I can see this output: `GET /api/students/5c11dc780c9da0001640c39d 200 359.665 ms - 11424
` , is it possible that we can display protocol used also ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37829617/get-http-version-of-incoming-request for how to get the HTTP version in nodeJS using express.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Standard one: `performance.timing.nextHopProtocol`

Non standard implemetation: `window.chrome.loadTimes().connectionInfo`

You can check in network tab of dev tools where h2 represents HTTP2,

[image: The Protocol column in the Network panel]

When the **Protocol** column says `h2` it means that the resource was sent with HTTP/2. The **Protocol** column is hidden by default. Right-click the table header and select **Protocol** to show it. See [Show more information for an example](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/#information).